# Can't locate Data/Dumper.pm when building dssp - perl is installed but cannot be found?

Tags: perl, installation, build, dependencies, autogen

I am trying to build dssp (https://github.com/cmbi/dssp) on a server-node (not on server-login), and I am facing a problem with how the system finds dependencies. I am working on a centos 7.

The procedure of building dssp is : `run ./autogen` to get a `configure.sh` file and then execute that one. Then run `make`.

Running `whereis perl` and `whereis perl5` I get:

```
[mavridks@haswell-182 dssp-2.3.0]$ whereis perl
perl: /usr/bin/perl /usr/share/man/man1/perl.1.gz

[mavridks@haswell-182 dssp-2.3.0]$ whereis perl5
perl5: /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5
```

Then, running `./autogen` I get the error:

```
Can't locate Data/Dumper.pm in @INC
   (@INC contains:
   /hits/sw/shared/apps/Autoconf/2.69-GCC-4.8.4/share/autoconf
   /usr/local/lib64/perl5
   /usr/local/share/perl5 
   /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl
   /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl
   /usr/lib64/perl5
   /usr/share/perl5 
   .)
   at /hits/sw/shared/apps/Autoconf/2.69-GCC-4.8.4/share/autoconf/Autom4te/C4che.pm line 33.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted
   at /hits/sw/shared/apps/Autoconf/2.69-GCC-4.8.4/share/autoconf/Autom4te/C4che.pm line 33.
Compilation failed in require
   at /hits/sw/shared/apps/Autoconf/2.69-GCC-4.8.4/bin/autom4te line 37.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted
   at /hits/sw/shared/apps/Autoconf/2.69-GCC-4.8.4/bin/autom4te line 37.
aclocal: error: echo failed with exit status: 2
```

(Line breaks added for readability.)

It seems to me that this error when `autoconf` is called has something to do with not locating correctly the Perl files or having more paths than it should? Another thought would be that I don't have root privileges on the server and that perhaps this creates a problem?

Any ideas or suggestions are welcomed.

NOTE:
The server uses a module system to load various dependencies. I need Autotools and Boost. The module I am using, if this is something of importance, are

```
[mavridks@haswell-182 dssp-2.3.0]$ module list

Currently Loaded Modules:
1) numactl/.2.0.10-GCC-4.8.4 (H)
2) hwloc/.1.10.1-GCC-4.8.4 (H)
3) OpenMPI/1.8.4-GCC-4.8.4
4) OpenBLAS/0.2.13-GCC-4.8.4-LAPACK-3.5.0
5) gompi/1.7.20                                                
6) FFTW/3.3.4-gompi-1.7.20                                    
7) ScaLAPACK/2.0.2-gompi-1.7.20-OpenBLAS-0.2.13-LAPACK-3.5.0
8) goolf/1.7.20
9) bzip2/.1.0.6-goolf-1.7.20 (H)
10) zlib/.1.2.8-goolf-1.7.20 (H)
11) Boost/1.58.0-goolf-1.7.20
12) slurm/18-08-4-1-hits
13) GCC/4.8.4
14) gcc/dummy
15) sge/dummy            
16) M4/1.4.17-GCC-4.8.4
17) Autoconf/2.69-GCC-4.8.4
18) Automake/1.15-GCC-4.8.4
19) libtool/2.4.6-GCC-4.8.4
20) Autotools/20150215-GCC-4.8.4

Where:
H:  Hidden Module
```

---

EDIT:

After the comment of  Håkon Hægland I get:

```
[mavridks@haswell-005 ~]$ perl --version | grep 'This is'
This is perl 5, version 30, subversion 0 (v5.30.0) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi

[mavridks@haswell-005 ~]$ perl -MData::Dumper -E 'say $INC{"Data/Dumper.pm"}'
/hits/sw/shared/apps/Perl/5.30.0-GCCcore-8.3.0/lib/perl5/5.30.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/Data/Dumper.pm
```

---

EDIT 2:
Here is the result after re-running the `./autogen`

```
[mavridks@haswell-112 dssp-2.3.0]
$ PERL5LIB=/hits/sw/shared/apps/Perl/5.30.0-GCCcore-8.3.0/lib/perl5/5.30.0 ./autogen.sh
/hits/sw/shared/apps/Automake/1.15-GCC-4.8.4/bin/aclocal:
   Perl lib version (5.30.0) doesn't match executable '/usr/bin/perl' version (5.16.3)
   at /hits/sw/shared/apps/Perl/5.30.0-GCCcore-8.3.0/lib/perl5/5.30.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/Config.pm line 62.
Compilation failed in require
   at /hits/sw/shared/apps/Automake/1.15-GCC-4.8.4/share/automake-1.15/Automake/Config.pm line 41.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted
   at /hits/sw/shared/apps/Automake/1.15-GCC-4.8.4/share/automake-1.15/Automake/Config.pm line 41.
Compilation failed in require
   at /hits/sw/shared/apps/Automake/1.15-GCC-4.8.4/bin/aclocal line 37.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted
   at /hits/sw/shared/apps/Automake/1.15-GCC-4.8.4/bin/aclocal line 37.
```

(Line breaks added for readability.)

EDIT 3:

After a lot of helpful comments and an answer I am adding some more info:

1. First one connects to the server login-node. Running whereis perl gives:

   [mavridks@haswell-login ~]$ whereis perl

   perl: /usr/bin/perl /usr/share/man/man1/perl.1.gz

and also, running

```
[mavridks@haswell-login ~]$ perl --version

This is perl 5, version 16, subversion 3 (v5.16.3) built for x86_64- 
linux-thread-multi
(with 39 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)
```

.Finally one gets:

```
[mavridks@haswell-login ~]$ perl -MData::Dumper -E 'say 
$INC{"Data/Dumper.pm"}'
/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/Data/Dumper.pm
```

Side-note: What do we get running perl -V?

a) On the login-node:

```
[mavridks@haswell-login ~]$ perl -V
Summary of my perl5 (revision 5 version 16 subversion 3) configuration:
   
  Platform:
    osname=linux, osvers=3.10.0-693.17.1.el7.x86_64, archname=x86_64-linux-thread-multi
    uname='linux x86-01.bsys.centos.org 3.10.0-693.17.1.el7.x86_64 #1 smp thu jan 25 20:13:58 utc 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 gnulinux '
    config_args='-des -Doptimize=-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic -Dccdlflags=-Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Dlddlflags=-shared -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic -Wl,-z,relro  -DDEBUGGING=-g -Dversion=5.16.3 -Dmyhostname=localhost -Dperladmin=root@localhost -Dcc=gcc -Dcf_by=Red Hat, Inc. -Dprefix=/usr -Dvendorprefix=/usr -Dsiteprefix=/usr/local -Dsitelib=/usr/local/share/perl5 -Dsitearch=/usr/local/lib64/perl5 -Dprivlib=/usr/share/perl5 -Dvendorlib=/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl -Darchlib=/usr/lib64/perl5 -Dvendorarch=/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl -Darchname=x86_64-linux-thread-multi -Dlibpth=/usr/local/lib64 /lib64 /usr/lib64 -Duseshrplib -Dusethreads -Duseithreads -Dusedtrace=/usr/bin/dtrace -Duselargefiles -Dd_semctl_semun -Di_db -Ui_ndbm -Di_gdbm -Di_shadow -Di_syslog -Dman3ext=3pm -Duseperlio -Dinstallusrbinperl=n -Ubincompat5005 -Uversiononly -Dpager=/usr/bin/less -isr -Dd_gethostent_r_proto -Ud_endhostent_r_proto -Ud_sethostent_r_proto -Ud_endprotoent_r_proto -Ud_setprotoent_r_proto -Ud_endservent_r_proto -Ud_setservent_r_proto -Dscriptdir=/usr/bin -Dusesitecustomize'
    hint=recommended, useposix=true, d_sigaction=define
    useithreads=define, usemultiplicity=define
    useperlio=define, d_sfio=undef, uselargefiles=define, usesocks=undef
    use64bitint=define, use64bitall=define, uselongdouble=undef
    usemymalloc=n, bincompat5005=undef
  Compiler:
    cc='gcc', ccflags ='-D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64',
    optimize='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic',
    cppflags='-D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include'
    ccversion='', gccversion='4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)', gccosandvers=''
    intsize=4, longsize=8, ptrsize=8, doublesize=8, byteorder=12345678
    d_longlong=define, longlongsize=8, d_longdbl=define, longdblsize=16
    ivtype='long', ivsize=8, nvtype='double', nvsize=8, Off_t='off_t', lseeksize=8
    alignbytes=8, prototype=define
  Linker and Libraries:
    ld='gcc', ldflags =' -fstack-protector'
    libpth=/usr/local/lib64 /lib64 /usr/lib64
    libs=-lresolv -lnsl -lgdbm -ldb -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lpthread -lc -lgdbm_compat
    perllibs=-lresolv -lnsl -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lpthread -lc
    libc=, so=so, useshrplib=true, libperl=libperl.so
    gnulibc_version='2.17'
  Dynamic Linking:
    dlsrc=dl_dlopen.xs, dlext=so, d_dlsymun=undef, ccdlflags='-Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib64/perl5/CORE'
    cccdlflags='-fPIC', lddlflags='-shared -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -Wl,-z,relro '


Characteristics of this binary (from libperl): 
  Compile-time options: HAS_TIMES MULTIPLICITY PERLIO_LAYERS
                        PERL_DONT_CREATE_GVSV PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT
                        PERL_MALLOC_WRAP PERL_PRESERVE_IVUV USE_64_BIT_ALL
                        USE_64_BIT_INT USE_ITHREADS USE_LARGE_FILES
                        USE_LOCALE USE_LOCALE_COLLATE USE_LOCALE_CTYPE
                        USE_LOCALE_NUMERIC USE_PERLIO USE_PERL_ATOF
                        USE_REENTRANT_API USE_SITECUSTOMIZE
  Locally applied patches:
    Fedora Patch1: Removes date check, Fedora/RHEL specific
    Fedora Patch3: support for libdir64
    Fedora Patch4: use libresolv instead of libbind
    Fedora Patch5: USE_MM_LD_RUN_PATH
    Fedora Patch6: Skip hostname tests, due to builders not being network capable
    Fedora Patch7: Dont run one io test due to random builder failures
    Fedora Patch9: Fix find2perl to translate ? glob properly (RT#113054)
    Fedora Patch10: Fix broken atof (RT#109318)
    Fedora Patch13: Clear $@ before "do" I/O error (RT#113730)
    Fedora Patch14: Do not truncate syscall() return value to 32 bits (RT#113980)
    Fedora Patch15: Override the Pod::Simple::parse_file (CPANRT#77530)
    Fedora Patch16: Do not leak with attribute on my variable (RT#114764)
    Fedora Patch17: Allow operator after numeric keyword argument (RT#105924)
    Fedora Patch18: Extend stack in File::Glob::glob, (RT#114984)
    Fedora Patch19: Do not crash when vivifying $|
    Fedora Patch20: Fix misparsing of maketext strings (CVE-2012-6329)
    Fedora Patch21: Add NAME headings to CPAN modules (CPANRT#73396)
    Fedora Patch22: Fix leaking tied hashes (RT#107000) [1]
    Fedora Patch23: Fix leaking tied hashes (RT#107000) [2]
    Fedora Patch24: Fix leaking tied hashes (RT#107000) [3]
    Fedora Patch25: Fix dead lock in PerlIO after fork from thread (RT#106212)
    Fedora Patch26: Make regexp safe in a signal handler (RT#114878)
    Fedora Patch27: Update h2ph(1) documentation (RT#117647)
    Fedora Patch28: Update pod2html(1) documentation (RT#117623)
    Fedora Patch29: Document Math::BigInt::CalcEmu requires Math::BigInt (CPAN RT#85015)
    RHEL Patch30: Use stronger algorithm needed for FIPS in t/op/crypt.t (RT#121591)
    RHEL Patch31: Make *DBM_File desctructors thread-safe (RT#61912)
    RHEL Patch32: Use stronger algorithm needed for FIPS in t/op/taint.t (RT#123338)
    RHEL Patch33: Remove CPU-speed-sensitive test in Benchmark test
    RHEL Patch34: Make File::Glob work with threads again
    RHEL Patch35: Fix CRLF conversion in ASCII FTP upload (CPAN RT#41642)
    RHEL Patch36: Do not leak the temp utf8 copy of namepv (CPAN RT#123786)
    RHEL Patch37: Fix duplicating PerlIO::encoding when spawning threads (RT#31923)
    RHEL Patch38: Add SSL support to Net::SMTP (CPAN RT#93823) [1]
    RHEL Patch39: Add SSL support to Net::SMTP (CPAN RT#93823) [2]
    RHEL Patch40: Add SSL support to Net::SMTP (CPAN RT#93823) [3]
    RHEL Patch41: Add SSL support to Net::SMTP (CPAN RT#93823) [4]
    RHEL Patch42: Do not overload ".." in Math::BigInt (CPAN RT#80182)
    RHEL Patch43: Fix CVE-2018-18311 Integer overflow leading to buffer overflow
  Built under linux
  Compiled at Jan 21 2019 22:09:19
  @INC:
    /usr/local/lib64/perl5
    /usr/local/share/perl5
    /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl
    /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl
    /usr/lib64/perl5
    /usr/share/perl5
    .
[mavridks@haswell-login ~]$
```

b) On the gpu-node:

```
[mavridks@haswell-179 ~]$ perl -V
Summary of my perl5 (revision 5 version 16 subversion 3) configuration:
   
  Platform:
    osname=linux, osvers=3.10.0-693.17.1.el7.x86_64, archname=x86_64-linux-thread-multi
    uname='linux x86-01.bsys.centos.org 3.10.0-693.17.1.el7.x86_64 #1 smp thu jan 25 20:13:58 utc 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 gnulinux '
    config_args='-des -Doptimize=-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic -Dccdlflags=-Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Dlddlflags=-shared -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic -Wl,-z,relro  -DDEBUGGING=-g -Dversion=5.16.3 -Dmyhostname=localhost -Dperladmin=root@localhost -Dcc=gcc -Dcf_by=Red Hat, Inc. -Dprefix=/usr -Dvendorprefix=/usr -Dsiteprefix=/usr/local -Dsitelib=/usr/local/share/perl5 -Dsitearch=/usr/local/lib64/perl5 -Dprivlib=/usr/share/perl5 -Dvendorlib=/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl -Darchlib=/usr/lib64/perl5 -Dvendorarch=/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl -Darchname=x86_64-linux-thread-multi -Dlibpth=/usr/local/lib64 /lib64 /usr/lib64 -Duseshrplib -Dusethreads -Duseithreads -Dusedtrace=/usr/bin/dtrace -Duselargefiles -Dd_semctl_semun -Di_db -Ui_ndbm -Di_gdbm -Di_shadow -Di_syslog -Dman3ext=3pm -Duseperlio -Dinstallusrbinperl=n -Ubincompat5005 -Uversiononly -Dpager=/usr/bin/less -isr -Dd_gethostent_r_proto -Ud_endhostent_r_proto -Ud_sethostent_r_proto -Ud_endprotoent_r_proto -Ud_setprotoent_r_proto -Ud_endservent_r_proto -Ud_setservent_r_proto -Dscriptdir=/usr/bin -Dusesitecustomize'
    hint=recommended, useposix=true, d_sigaction=define
    useithreads=define, usemultiplicity=define
    useperlio=define, d_sfio=undef, uselargefiles=define, usesocks=undef
    use64bitint=define, use64bitall=define, uselongdouble=undef
    usemymalloc=n, bincompat5005=undef
  Compiler:
    cc='gcc', ccflags ='-D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64',
    optimize='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic',
    cppflags='-D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include'
    ccversion='', gccversion='4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)', gccosandvers=''
    intsize=4, longsize=8, ptrsize=8, doublesize=8, byteorder=12345678
    d_longlong=define, longlongsize=8, d_longdbl=define, longdblsize=16
    ivtype='long', ivsize=8, nvtype='double', nvsize=8, Off_t='off_t', lseeksize=8
    alignbytes=8, prototype=define
  Linker and Libraries:
    ld='gcc', ldflags =' -fstack-protector'
    libpth=/usr/local/lib64 /lib64 /usr/lib64
    libs=-lresolv -lnsl -lgdbm -ldb -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lpthread -lc -lgdbm_compat
    perllibs=-lresolv -lnsl -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lpthread -lc
    libc=, so=so, useshrplib=true, libperl=libperl.so
    gnulibc_version='2.17'
  Dynamic Linking:
    dlsrc=dl_dlopen.xs, dlext=so, d_dlsymun=undef, ccdlflags='-Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib64/perl5/CORE'
    cccdlflags='-fPIC', lddlflags='-shared -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -Wl,-z,relro '


Characteristics of this binary (from libperl): 
  Compile-time options: HAS_TIMES MULTIPLICITY PERLIO_LAYERS
                        PERL_DONT_CREATE_GVSV PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT
                        PERL_MALLOC_WRAP PERL_PRESERVE_IVUV USE_64_BIT_ALL
                        USE_64_BIT_INT USE_ITHREADS USE_LARGE_FILES
                        USE_LOCALE USE_LOCALE_COLLATE USE_LOCALE_CTYPE
                        USE_LOCALE_NUMERIC USE_PERLIO USE_PERL_ATOF
                        USE_REENTRANT_API USE_SITECUSTOMIZE
  Locally applied patches:
    Fedora Patch1: Removes date check, Fedora/RHEL specific
    Fedora Patch3: support for libdir64
    Fedora Patch4: use libresolv instead of libbind
    Fedora Patch5: USE_MM_LD_RUN_PATH
    Fedora Patch6: Skip hostname tests, due to builders not being network capable
    Fedora Patch7: Dont run one io test due to random builder failures
    Fedora Patch9: Fix find2perl to translate ? glob properly (RT#113054)
    Fedora Patch10: Fix broken atof (RT#109318)
    Fedora Patch13: Clear $@ before "do" I/O error (RT#113730)
    Fedora Patch14: Do not truncate syscall() return value to 32 bits (RT#113980)
    Fedora Patch15: Override the Pod::Simple::parse_file (CPANRT#77530)
    Fedora Patch16: Do not leak with attribute on my variable (RT#114764)
    Fedora Patch17: Allow operator after numeric keyword argument (RT#105924)
    Fedora Patch18: Extend stack in File::Glob::glob, (RT#114984)
    Fedora Patch19: Do not crash when vivifying $|
    Fedora Patch20: Fix misparsing of maketext strings (CVE-2012-6329)
    Fedora Patch21: Add NAME headings to CPAN modules (CPANRT#73396)
    Fedora Patch22: Fix leaking tied hashes (RT#107000) [1]
    Fedora Patch23: Fix leaking tied hashes (RT#107000) [2]
    Fedora Patch24: Fix leaking tied hashes (RT#107000) [3]
    Fedora Patch25: Fix dead lock in PerlIO after fork from thread (RT#106212)
    Fedora Patch26: Make regexp safe in a signal handler (RT#114878)
    Fedora Patch27: Update h2ph(1) documentation (RT#117647)
    Fedora Patch28: Update pod2html(1) documentation (RT#117623)
    Fedora Patch29: Document Math::BigInt::CalcEmu requires Math::BigInt (CPAN RT#85015)
    RHEL Patch30: Use stronger algorithm needed for FIPS in t/op/crypt.t (RT#121591)
    RHEL Patch31: Make *DBM_File desctructors thread-safe (RT#61912)
    RHEL Patch32: Use stronger algorithm needed for FIPS in t/op/taint.t (RT#123338)
    RHEL Patch33: Remove CPU-speed-sensitive test in Benchmark test
    RHEL Patch34: Make File::Glob work with threads again
    RHEL Patch35: Fix CRLF conversion in ASCII FTP upload (CPAN RT#41642)
    RHEL Patch36: Do not leak the temp utf8 copy of namepv (CPAN RT#123786)
    RHEL Patch37: Fix duplicating PerlIO::encoding when spawning threads (RT#31923)
    RHEL Patch38: Add SSL support to Net::SMTP (CPAN RT#93823) [1]
    RHEL Patch39: Add SSL support to Net::SMTP (CPAN RT#93823) [2]
    RHEL Patch40: Add SSL support to Net::SMTP (CPAN RT#93823) [3]
    RHEL Patch41: Add SSL support to Net::SMTP (CPAN RT#93823) [4]
    RHEL Patch42: Do not overload ".." in Math::BigInt (CPAN RT#80182)
  Built under linux
  Compiled at Oct 30 2018 18:59:43
  @INC:
    /usr/local/lib64/perl5
    /usr/local/share/perl5
    /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl
    /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl
    /usr/lib64/perl5
    /usr/share/perl5
    .
```

2. Then one connects to a gpu-node. It seems we still have the same perl:

   [mavridks@haswell-179 ~]$ whereis perl
   perl: /usr/bin/perl /usr/share/man/man1/perl.1.gz

but now Data/Dumber is no more ( running perl -MData::Dumper -E 'say $INC{"Data/Dumper.pm"}' ):

```
[mavridks@haswell-179 ~]$ perl -MData::Dumper -E 'say $INC{"Data/Dumper.pm"}'
Can't locate Data/Dumper.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .).
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
```

3. Then the IT department suggested loading the perl module; the server is built on a module system where all groups have the ability to load software as modules ( appending the right files in the path - this is the system used https://lmod.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#overview). So, if we run module load Perl we have:

   [mavridks@haswell-179 ~]$ whereis perl
   perl: /usr/bin/perl /hits/sw/shared/apps/Perl/5.30.0-GCCcore-8.3.0/bin/perl /usr/share/man/man1/perl.1.gz

which means we have changed something( the distribution used may I say?). But now we have:

```
[mavridks@haswell-179 ~]$ perl -MData::Dumper -E 'say $INC{"Data/Dumper.pm"}'
/hits/sw/shared/apps/Perl/5.30.0-GCCcore-8.3.0/lib/perl5/5.30.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/Data/Dumper.pm
```

which means we have the Data/Dumper on the system.

3. Finally, one need to load all the autotools as a module too. Then, it seems that the execution of the autogen.sh script is looking for perl modules from the system ( the one from login and not gpu) but of course it can't locate them.

   [mavridks@haswell-179 dssp-2.3.0]$ ./autogen.sh
   Can't locate Data/Dumper.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /hits/sw/shared/apps/Autoconf/2.69-GCC-4.8.4/share/autoconf /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at /hits/sw/shared/apps/Autoconf/2.69-GCC-4.8.4/share/autoconf/Autom4te/C4che.pm line 33.
   BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /hits/sw/shared/apps/Autoconf/2.69-GCC-4.8.4/share/autoconf/Autom4te/C4che.pm line 33.
   Compilation failed in require at /hits/sw/shared/apps/Autoconf/2.69-GCC-4.8.4/bin/autom4te line 37.
   BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /hits/sw/shared/apps/Autoconf/2.69-GCC-4.8.4/bin/autom4te line 37.
   aclocal: error: echo failed with exit status: 2

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222639/discussion-on-question-by-constantine-black-cant-locate-data-dumper-pm-when-bui).

Comment: basedon your updates, I would say that you have two perl installations; 5.16 and 5.30. How ./autogen.sh is calling perl?

Comment: @mabe02 From the error when running autogen.sh I understand that it tries to find perl on a wrong installation. Regarding the script, it just calls autotools. That is: [mavridks@haswell-142 dssp-2.3.0]$ cat autogen.sh 
#!/bin/sh

aclocal \
&& autoheader \
&& automake --add-missing \
&& autoconf

Thanks

Comment: @ikegami  thought it would be more clear now on how the system and the modular distributions are changing after moving from the login-node to the gpu-node. You think I should remove it?

Comment: @ikegami Ok then, I will just add it to the end of the post as extra information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two builds of `perl` installed.

- `/usr/bin/perl`, v5.16.3<sup>[1]</sup>
- `/hits/sw/shared/apps/Perl/5.30.0-GCCcore-8.3.0/bin/perl`, v5.30.0<sup>[2]</sup>

I shall dub them "system `perl`" and "modular `perl`" respectively.

- The system `perl` doesn't have Data::Dumper installed.<sup>[3]</sup>
- The modular `perl` does have Data::Dumper installed.<sup>[4]</sup>

`whereis` shows only the system `perl` in your PATH, but later commands show `perl` invoking the modular `perl`. So either `perl` is an alias for the modular `perl`,<sup>[5]</sup> or you ran your tests in different environments (i.e. your PATH changed).

---

**Is it appropriate to set `PERL5LIB`?**

At one point, you set env var `PERL5LIB` to `/hits/sw/shared/apps/Perl/5.30.0-GCCcore-8.3.0/lib/perl5/5.30.0`. This is not appropriate.

This is incorrect for the system `perl`.<sup>[6]</sup>

This is unnecessary for the modular `perl`. It is redundant.<sup>[7]</sup>

---

**Why doesn't the system `perl` have Data::Dumper installed?**

Perl has certain modules that come with it. For virtually as long as support for modules has existed in Perl, this has included Data::Dumper. Data::Dumper should always be available.

However, certain linux distros split Perl into multiple packages. It appears that Data::Dumper is found in the [`perl(Data::Dumper)` package](https://pkgs.org/download/perl(Data::Dumper)) in CentOS 7.

So the solution is to install that package.

Since Data::Dumper is dual-lived, it can also be installed from CPAN. This doesn't require any special permissions. That said, I usually recommend installing `perl` locally instead of messing with the system `perl`. It seems you already have such a Perl. This leads us to the next sub-answer.

---

**What if I want to use the modular `perl`?**

I'm not sure.

A quick experiment leads me to believe this can be solved by simply placing the modular `perl` in the PATH before `/usr/bin`.

```sh
export PATH="/hits/sw/shared/apps/Perl/5.30.0-GCCcore-8.3.0/bin:$PATH"
```

Alternatively, quick experiments suggest that both of the following also work:

```sh
./configure PERL=/hits/sw/shared/apps/Perl/5.30.0-GCCcore-8.3.0/bin/perl
```

```sh
PERL=/hits/sw/shared/apps/Perl/5.30.0-GCCcore-8.3.0/bin/perl ./configure
```

If these don't do the trick, this can be asked as a separate question.

---

**What if I disagree with something in this answer?**

Some of my statements were guesses. For example, `/hits/sw/shared/apps/Perl/5.30.0-GCCcore-8.3.0/bin/perl` wasn't mentioned anywhere in your question. If you believe I've made a mistake, please provide the output of the following command (parens and all):

```sh
(
   echo 'System perl:'
   /usr/bin/perl -v | grep 'This is'
   PERL5LIB= /usr/bin/perl -e'CORE::say for @INC'
   echo
   echo "Data::Dumper in system perl?"
   PERL5LIB= /usr/bin/perl -e'
      use Data::Dumper;
      CORE::say $Data::Dumper::VERSION;
      CORE::say INC{"Data/Dumper.pm"};
   '
   echo
   echo 'Modular perl:'
   /hits/sw/shared/apps/Perl/5.30.0-GCCcore-8.3.0/bin/perl -v | grep 'This is'
   PERL5LIB= /hits/sw/shared/apps/Perl/5.30.0-GCCcore-8.3.0/bin/perl -e'CORE::say for @INC'
   echo
   echo "Data::Dumper in modular perl?"
   PERL5LIB= /hits/sw/shared/apps/Perl/5.30.0-GCCcore-8.3.0/bin/perl -e'
      use Data::Dumper;
      CORE::say $Data::Dumper::VERSION;
      CORE::say $INC{"Data/Dumper.pm"};
   '
   echo
   echo 'Perl env vars:'
   perl -e'CORE::say "$_: $ENV{$_}" for grep /^PERL/, keys(%ENV)'
   echo
   echo 'type perl:'
   type perl
)
```

---

Footnotes.

1. This can be verified using

   ```sh
   /usr/bin/perl -v | grep 'This is'
   ```
2. This can be verified using

   ```sh
   /hits/sw/shared/apps/Perl/5.30.0-GCCcore-8.3.0/bin/perl -v | grep 'This is'
   ```
3. This can be verified using

   ```sh
   /usr/bin/perl -e'use Data::Dumper;'
   ```
4. This can be verified using

   ```sh
   /hits/sw/shared/apps/Perl/5.30.0-GCCcore-8.3.0/bin/perl -e'use Data::Dumper;'
   ```
5. In some shells (incl `dash`, `bash` and `ksh`), this can be verified using

   ```sh
   type perl
   ```
6. This is what lead to `Perl lib version (5.30.0) doesn't match executable '/usr/bin/perl' version (5.16.3)`.
7. This can be verified using

   ```sh
   PERL5LIB= /hits/sw/shared/apps/Perl/5.30.0-GCCcore-8.3.0/bin/perl -e'CORE::say for @INC;'
   ```

Comment: Indeed, on a gpu-node, only the modular perl seems to have the data/dumber.

Comment: It's pretty common. Explanation provided.

Comment: Regarding installing packages on my own: this would be by 99.9% percent impossible due to permissions. Only the IT group would be able to install it.

Yes, I am reading through everything you wrote and I am providing the best feedback I can.

If I can't install the package, and the only way is to use the modular perl, then it seems that ( see my last edit) one must configure autotools where to look correctly?

Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry if I am adding too much info here, just to provide as clear information as I can.

Comment: Data::Dumper is on CPAN --it's what's called a dual-life modules-- so it can be installed as an ordinary modules. No special permissions are necessary for that. However, I dislike messing with the system Perl. I normally recommend installing a local Perl instead. And you already have that.

Comment: As for how to tell the build process to use the existing Perl, that's already covered by the answer. Maybe it's just a question of adding it to the PATH, maybe it's something you need to ask a Question about.

Comment: Thank you again. I am adding a final edit with the results of the code you wrote for the more help paragraph, with the results.

Comment: Please don't unless you disagree with something I said. (*Perfection is achieved not when there is nothing left to add, but when there is nothing left to take away.* - Antoine de Saint-Exupery.)

Comment: I agree, but on your post you are asking for the results of the command ( with the parentheses and all I mean). Did I misunderstood?

Comment: Some of my statements were guesses. For example, `/hits/sw/shared/apps/Perl/5.30.0-GCCcore-8.3.0/bin/perl` wasn't mentioned anywhere in your question. If you believe everything I said is correct, the command won't provide anything new.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I have made a comment in the chat. I will of course now accept you answer. Thank you again for all the help and the details.

Comment: Updated "*What if I want to use the modular `perl`?*"

Comment: Thats what I was looking at right now, since it seems... cpan command is not found on system perl on gpu-node. Thank you again, really. I think we can consider the problem solved.